# how to set the default date if the mindate is disabled?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Here i used the bootstrapdatepicker to show the date.

In the start date, the date comes dynamicaaly from the service should be enable when i set min date.

Here default date is not selectable if the mindate is disabled.

Below i mentioned the code.

for example $scope.createdOn = "2017-02-02"

```
$("#fromDate")
.datepicker(
{
dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
defaultDate: $scope.createdOn,
minDate:0,
// beforeShowDay: function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
// var today = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());
// console.log(today);
// var enableDays = [$scope.createdOn,today];
// var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd', date);
// if(date < new Date())
// {
// return [false];
// }
// return [true];

// },

onSelect:function(date){
$scope.createdOn = $scope.createdOn;
console.log($scope.createdOn);
}
})
$('#fromDate').datepicker("setDate", new Date($scope.createdOn));
$('#fromDate .ui-datepicker-prev').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
$('#fromDate .ui-datepicker-next').addClass('ui-state-disabled');




$("#toDate")
.datepicker(
{
defaultDate: $scope.expireOn,
dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
minDate : 1,
onSelect:function(date){
$scope.expireOn = date;
console.log($scope.expireOn);
}

});
$('#toDate').datepicker("setDate", new Date($scope.expireOn));
});
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: It would be better if you prepare a fiddle for us to work on it

Comment: read [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) as `minDate` will override `defaultDate`

Comment: Is there any possible to set default date if mindate overrides @Raviteja

Comment: Could you explain your requirement exactly?

Comment: To enable the default date if min-date disabled the default date

Comment: Suppose the date i need to set is '2017-02-02'. I assigned the date to default date. So it will selectable. Suppose if i use the minDate : 0. Default date is not active. It should be in active stage